# iOS background agent

Tags: ios, background

I've read plenty of times that we only can run background tasks for location, voip and audio.

Well, I just noticed that in Windows Phone there is a possibility to set up a background agent that starts every 30 minutes and runs for X seconds, then it's killed.

Is there any kind of agent in iOS?

I need to upload location every 30 mins. However, if I use significant location changes, if I'm at home for the weekend and my app is closed, it won't upload any location until I go out.

So, how would you do this?

Thank you!

Comment: If it doesn't upload any new location (since you haven't moved), then why can't you just use the last location that *was* uploaded (again, since you haven't gone anywhere)?

Comment: Because I also show the last update time and, if I haven't got that agent, then It'll show "updated 2 days ago".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing of this kind. But what is wrong with not uploading the location when it didn't change?

Comment: Same answer here: Because I also show the last update time and, if I haven't got that agent, then It'll show "updated 2 days ago". So there's no way for doing this...